# NodeJS, difference between N-API, nan, node-gyp and cmake-js

Tags: node.js, cmake, node-gyp, n-api, cmake-js

I am trying to learn how to use C and/or C++ libraries inside NodeJS.

But it is somewhat confusing the many different tools and approaches, and the relation between them.

What is the difference between [NodeJS N-API](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html) and "[nan](https://github.com/nodejs/nan)", and what is the role played by [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) and/or [cmake-js](https://github.com/cmake-js/cmake-js).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are starting a fresh development that involve building native module, then N-API could be an excellent choice. The N-API is the node.js core C API to interact with underlying JavaScript engine (it is relatively a new addition). It provides Application Binary Interface (ABI) stability guarantee across node.js versions.

While I was learning the N-API, a GitHub repository has been created with short note and example. Hope this may help you to get understanding the evolution history and a jump start for creating C/C++ native modules.
https://github.com/msatyan/MyNodeC

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Since `node-gyp` is mentioned in the repository you linked, can you elaborate about `cmake-js` vs `node-gyp`?

Comment: If you are a C++ developer,familiar with cmake, use cmake-js; otherwise use node-gyp.